Sheets not respecting preferredContentSize as FormSheet on iPad
I use SheetPresentationControllers to present a few ViewControllers as sheets with custom detents and all that on iPhone, or compact size classes. On iPad I want the same views presented as "form sheets" (basically the same view but detached from bottom and floating). For some reason these views take up almost the full screen (save margins) and refuse to respect the set preferedContentSize of their ViewControllers.

The key turns out to be set:
viewController.sheetPresentationController?.prefersPageSizing = false

Note: Your preferredContentSize must use real numbers. Using UIView.noIntrinsicMetric seems to, again, cause the value to be ignored.
What can you do about it?
This API makes very little naming sense to me versus something like usePreferredWidth. If you agree please feel free to file a feedback and mention/dupe FB15569536. ‍♂️
